# Блокировка выхода из приложения

Tags: java, android

Производственная необходимость, чтобы опционально была возможность блокировки выхода из нашего приложения в системный лончер, systemUI(запрет на открытие), системные настройки.

Возможно ли такое реализовать?

Root прав нету, версия Android 7 - 9.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices

Comment: Прочитал, очень сложно понять:) Если не сложно, как это работает? Можете прокомментировать?

Comment: а вы подумайте, если бы была потенциальная возможность, то по крайней мере миллион хакеров это сделали бы